# Accessing the GUI from a background Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose, invoke

I've made a sample program which generates every second 2000 integers on a Background thread, and when it finishes it fires an event which draws graph on the GUI from the random generated data (I have a sleep inside my thread to simulate a real measurement).

```
private void SetChart(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series)
{
  if (InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetChartCallback d = new SetChartCallback(SetChart);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { series });
  }
  else
  {
    chart1.Series[0] = series;
    chart1.Series[0].Name = "Generated Data";
  }
}
```

I found this approach on the MSDN site. It's working fine, the only problem is, when I close the application. Sometimes an error meassage shows up :

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Form1'.

When I close the program it disposes all the elements, how can I prevent this error not to happen?

Comment: The recommended approach is to not let the form close until all your background threads are completed.  e.g. disable a close butter, or override the close event to inform the user something is currently happening in the background and to try again later.  Otherwise, if you let the form close it will be gone while the background processing is still happening...

Comment: Now I am checking the Thread.IsAlive boolean, but if it returns true and I call the thread.Join() - the program freezes and nothing happens.

Comment: Where are you calling thread.join?  if you call that in the close of the form it will block until your background thread completes--that's what Join does.

Comment: Yes I call it in the close of the form (FormClosed event). This is what i want to achieve to finish this thread before the program closes, but the Join() doesn't help, the program freezes and it never shuts down.

Comment: Yes, that's that `Join` does; it blocks the current thread until the other thread completes.  If your background thread takes another couple of minutes to complete you application will look *hung*.  That's why you tell the user something is going on in the background and don't let them close the app (see my first comment).

Comment: Yes I understand this, but it takes only 1 second for my background thread to finish his work. So therefore I dont understand why it doesnt shuts down.

Comment: If you really want to understand what's going on you could add trace output to show what each thread is doing. This should confirm that the background thread sometimes finishes _after_ the form has been disposed. I would do what @PeterRitchie suggested in the first comment above; you could also make your background thread support cancellation.

Comment: Thank You guys. Probably I can change the code a little bit and then there will no problems with the termination.

Comment: Based on your description you've got a continually running background thread that does something every second.  If you post the code, someone can probably give you more accurate information.

Comment: I have 2 threads in my code. The first thread simulates the measurement, the second does the data analysis. I have an AutoResetEvent in my first thread, so yes it is running continually. When it finishes the generation of the numbers, it runs the second thread. The second thread does the drawing of the data to the GUI. So the problem is with my second thread

Comment: your thread is not drawing the gui, it's invoking a method on your form. that runs in the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, you are right its invoking the method. I will post here my tomorrow.

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be a symptom. You might want to ask another question, post the code that kicking off your threads and what you want to do. You seem to have grasped the wrong end of the stick here.

Answer (score 1):

You've closed the form, but the thread is still running, so when it completes It tries to invoke a method on the disposed object. Your form.

You can wait for the thread to complete.
Or you can signal it somehow to stop messing about creating integers you don't need anymore and quit it's loop right now.

Don't be tempted to just kill it. Very bad habit, you don't want get into that.

Comment: In the Form.FormClosed event I am checking for the Thread.IsAlive state. When it returns true I am trying to Join() the thread (Or is there any other way to wait for the thread to complete its task ?), because with calling the Join method the whole program freezes.

Comment: Join will wait, but it will freeze your main thread. Does the thread terminate on completion. If it doesn't it's never going to finish until you signal it to.

Comment: It's the default. Might be worth posting your thread create and start code.

Answer (score 1):

The proper approach, ugly as it may seem, is probably to catch the exception and swallow it.  It's probably not reasonable for the form's `Dispose` to block until the background thread exits (a situation which could easily cause deadlock); nor does the Framework provide any method which says try to `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` this method on a control or form, but simply do nothing if it's been disposed.  Thus, your best bet is probably to write `TryInvoke` and `TryBeginInvoke` methods which will do that by catching any exception that results if the form has been disposed.  You might use an `IsDisposed` check within such a method, but you should realize that because of some Framework quirks, there are some race conditions which cannot be resolved nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be to check IsDisposed. Something like this:

```
private void SetChart(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series)
{
    if (IsDisposed)
       return;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that it doesnt solve the problem. The same thing happens like before